# Save only one field of an entity to another table

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin

How do I only save a certain field/property of an Entity for another entity?

I have a `Key` entity with id and name properties.

In my `Door` entity, I would like to accept a `Key` but only save in the database the `id`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `@Transient` annotation. Example from the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html):

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id int id;
    @Transient User currentUser;
    ...
}
```

`@Transient` will mark the annotated element to not be persisted.